# Raphael .mouseup() function only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm attempting to have a draggable element snap back to the position of another element in Rapheal after dragging it.  The problem I'm experiencing is that the `.mouseup()` function only executes the functions within it once.  After you drag or move the element again, it will not longer execute the positioning functions I have within it.

My end goal is:

1. Drag the red square
2. When the red square is let go off (mouseup), snap square back to the blue square position.

Here is the code I've tried using, but I can't seem to get it to function correctly:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GWEU/3/

**Javascript:**

```
//Makes elements Draggable.
Raphael.st.draggable = function() {
    var me = this,
        lx = 0,
        ly = 0,
        ox = 0,
        oy = 0,
        moveFnc = function(dx, dy) {
            lx = dx + ox;
            ly = dy + oy;
            me.transform('t' + lx + ',' + ly);
        },
        startFnc = function() {
            //window.draggedElement = this;
        },
        endFnc = function() {
            ox = lx;
            oy = ly;
        };

    this.drag(moveFnc, startFnc, endFnc);
};

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var paper = Raphael(container, '539', '537');

var shape1 = paper.rect(50,50, 50,50);
shape1.attr({x: '50',y: '50',fill: 'red','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});
shape1Set = paper.set(shape1);
shape1Set.draggable();

var shape2 = paper.rect(50,50, 50,50);
shape2.attr({x: '150',y: '50',fill: 'blue','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});


shape1Set.mousedown(function(event) {
    console.log('mousedown');
});
shape1Set.mouseup(function(event) {
    console.log('mouseup'); 
    positionElementToElement(shape1, shape2);
});

$('#runPosition').click(function () {
   positionElementToElement(shape1, shape2); 
});

$('#runPosition2').click(function () {
   positionElementToElement2(shape1, shape2); 
});

function positionElementToElement(element, positionTargetElement)
{
    var parentBBox = positionTargetElement.getBBox();
        parent_x = parentBBox.x;
        parent_y = parentBBox.y;
        parent_width = parentBBox.width;
        parent_height = parentBBox.height;

    var elementBBox = element.getBBox();
        element_width = elementBBox.width;
        element_height = elementBBox.height;  

    var x_pos = parent_x + (parent_width / 2) - (element_width / 2) + 100;
    var y_pos = parent_y + (parent_height / 2) - (element_height / 2) + 100;

    console.log('Positioning element to: '+x_pos+' '+y_pos);
    element.animate({'x' : x_pos, 'y' : y_pos}, 100);
}

function positionElementToElement2(element, positionTargetElement)
{
    var parentBBox = positionTargetElement.getBBox();
        parent_x = parentBBox.x;
        parent_y = parentBBox.y;
        parent_width = parentBBox.width;
        parent_height = parentBBox.height;

    var elementBBox = element.getBBox();
        element_width = elementBBox.width;
        element_height = elementBBox.height;  

    var x_pos = parent_x + (parent_width / 2) - (element_width / 2);
    var y_pos = parent_y + (parent_height / 2) - (element_height / 2);

    console.log('Positioning element to: '+x_pos+' '+y_pos);
    element.animate({'x' : x_pos, 'y' : y_pos}, 100);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="runPosition">Run Position</a>
<a href="#" id="runPosition2">Run Position2</a>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Notes:**

1. I've duplicated the `positionElementToElement()` function and set one of them with an offset.  I've binded both functions to the `Run Position 1` and `Run Position 2` links.
2. After dragging the item, clicking the `Run Position 1` link no longer sets the square back where it should go (even though the function is logging the same x/y coordinates as when it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do this properly.

You have to modify the `x` and `y` attributes of the element directly.

It's also important to note that when retrieving the x and y attributes from an element using `element.attr('x');` or `element.attr('y');` it returns a string value, not an integer.  Because of this, you have to use `parseInt()` on these returned values to properly add up the movement x and y values to apply to the element when it moves.

The following code will snap the red square to the blue square, when the red square is moved.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/naQQ2/2/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var R = Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%"),      
        shape1 = R.rect(50,50, 50,50);
        shape1.attr({x:'50',y:'50',fill: 'red','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});

        shape2 = R.rect(50,50, 50,50);
        shape2.attr({x:'150',y:'50',fill: 'blue','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'});

    var start = function () {
        console.log(this);

        this.ox = parseInt(this.attr('x'));
        this.oy = parseInt(this.attr('y'));
        this.animate({opacity: .25}, 500, ">");
    },
        move = function (dx, dy) {     
            this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
        },
        up = function () {
            //Snap to shape2 on mouseup.
            var snapx = parseInt(shape2.attr("x"));
                snapy = parseInt(shape2.attr("y"));

            this.animate({x: snapx, y: snapy}, 100);            
            this.animate({opacity: 1}, 500, ">");
        };
    R.set(shape1, shape2).drag(move, start, up);   
};
```